# changes in /etc/login.defs no taking over

Tags: login

I've made changes to the /etc/login.defs:

PASS_MIN_LEN   3

Restarted the server, even created a new user but I'm still getting error that the password is to short ...

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

The `/etc/login.defs` is a very old way of configuring login-related settings, and many things that used to be there are now handled in some other way.

In particular, the password quality checks are now usually handled by the PAM modules, whose configuration can be found in `/etc/pam.d` (= which modules are invoked when) and `/etc/security` (= the configuration files for individual modules, if needed).

When using the `passwd` command to change a password, the `/etc/pam.d/passwd` file is read to determine which PAM modules to use. Usually the command-specific PAM configuration files will just refer to other files in the same directory with an  `@include` directive: for example, on Debian 10, the `/etc/pam.d/passwd` file just contains one non-comment line: `@include common-password`. (Linux distributions unrelated to Debian may use a different set-up here)

The `/etc/pam.d/common-password` file then defines the PAM modules involved in a password change process (no matter whether you're doing it on a command line or using some GUI tool). From there, you will find a line that mentions `pam_unix.so`.

`pam_unix.so` is the PAM module responsible for the standard unix-style password storage using `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow`. It also includes minimum length checking; the default minimum length is 6 characters in Debian 10, but can be adjusted by adding a `minlen=N` option to the `password ... pam_unix.so` line.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you. I'm surprised that the offical RHEL RHCSA materials are still referencing /etc/login.def.